# How to call a java REST web service from android phone

Tags: java, android, rest

I have built the client using Android and the server using java REST web services.I am able to access the server while running the android code on emulator.However,when I install the .apk file on my mobile and try calling the 
REST web service;it does not connect.No communication between the two is initiated.

Comment: Was there any error message shown?

Comment: Are your web services visible 'outside'? Can you access them using any web browser installed on computer other than your server? It looks like some networking issue (local access - ok, remote - not).

Comment: Can you please posts the logs messages ?

Comment: First make sure you can hit the webserver from your phone's browser as @jaroslawj suggested.  If you can, then its probably a code problem and you'd need to actually post code.

Comment: My guess would either be the URL you're using to access the web service isn't available externally (e.g. you're using the localhost url) or a firewall issue. Also make sure the devices are on the same physical network (I.e. don't use 3g on the phone, use WiFi)

Comment: I am able to access the web service from browser on my computer.However when i try to access the same from the browser of my phone,I get HTTP Error 504:Gateway Timeout

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using your public IP address to connect to your server(from client) or not. The URL that you provide in your client should have public IP and not private one.

---

To determine public/private IPs, please go through the below link

http://www.howtogeek.com/117371/how-to-find-your-computers-private-public-ip-addresses/